# Filter an array by values which aren't a property value in an array of objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of values, for example:

```
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And I have another array, containing objects, for example:

```
let objects = [{name: 'Dennis', value: 2}, {name: 'Charlie', value: 4}];
```

I would like to produce an array that only contains values that aren't present in the value property of my objects.
So from the examples above, I would return an array of `[1, 3, 5]`

What I've got at the moment is:

```
let missingValues = [];
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (!objects.filter(obj => obj.value === values[i]) {
        missingValues.push(values[i]);
    }
}
```

This works, but feels slightly messy, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter the values with a look up in the objects array.

```js
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    objects = [{ name: 'Dennis', value: 2 }, { name: 'Charlie', value: 4 }],
    result = values.filter(v => !objects.find(({ value }) => value === v));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works well thanks. Out of curiosity, say `values` was also an array of objects like `objects`. Would you simply alter the `.find` to the property you're interested in and then add a map on the end? Or go for a completely different approach?

Comment: then i would use `!objects.find(({ value }) => value.includes(v))`.

Answer (score 2):

> ...is there a more efficient way to do this?

I assume you really mean "efficient" (as opposed to "concise").

Yes, you can build an object or `Set` containing the values from the second array, and then use that to filter instead:

```js
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let objects = [{name: 'Dennis', value: 2}, {name: 'Charlie', value: 4}];

let valueSet = new Set();
for (const obj of objects) {
    valueSet.add(obj.value);
}

let missingValues = values.filter(value => !valueSet.has(value));

console.log(missingValues);
```

(You can also use an object for the same thing, if you prefer. `let valueSet = Object.create(null);` then `valueSet[value] = true` and `!valueSet[value]`.)

This is only worth doing if the product of the arrays is quite large (hundreds of thousands of entries) or you're doing this a **lot**.

Comment: I don't think I'd ever be dealing with much more than 100-150 entires and it won't be executed that frequently. But thanks for this answer, interesting to see a different approach